# Why not consider $a<0, k<0$ case while factoring this polynomial using method of undetermined coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Below is factoring a polynomial using method of undetermined coefficient.

While solving the system, my textbook (not English) says it is OK to think that $a>0, k>0$. Why? Why cannot it be like that: $a<0, k<0$ ? Ok, they both shall have same sign, but why do we consider only "both positive"?

Is there any reasoning that allows us skip considering the other possiblility ($a<0, k<0$) ?

[image]

Comment: Is it $a$ and $k$ you mean? For this pair, if both are negative, you can multiply each factor by $-1$, and since $(-1)^2=1$ you get a valid factorisation where both leading coefficients are positive.

Answer (score 0):

Because the author of the book wants integer coefficients. The second case it's $a=k=-1.$

There is much more stronger method:

For all real $k$ we have:
$$2x^4-x^3-9x^2-x+1=\left(kx^2-\frac{1}{2}x+1\right)^2-x^2\left((k^2-2)x^2-(k-1)x+\left(2k+\frac{37}{4}\right)\right).$$
Now, we ca choose a value of $k$ such that $k^2-2>0$ and 
$$(k^2-2)x^2-(k-1)x+\left(2k+\frac{37}{4}\right)=(ax+b)^2$$ for some reals $a$ and $b$.

For which we need also
$$(k-1)^2-4(k^2-2)\left(2k+\frac{37}{4}\right)=0,$$ which gives $k=-\frac{3}{2}.$

Id est, $$2x^4-x^3-9x^2-x+1=\left(-\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+1\right)^2-x^2\left(\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+\frac{25}{4}\right)=$$
$$=\left(\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}x-1\right)^2-\left(x\left(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}\right)\right)^2=(x^2-2x-1)(2x^2+3x-1).$$

Comment: Does the technique presented in this question actually work for this polynomial? What are the consistent values, if any, of b and l?

Comment: @Roy Simpson No, it does not help for all polynomial. But we can solve any quartic equation by the way, which I sowed.